# Windows 8.1: PC crashes after opening metro app

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, bsod, modern-ui

I recently installed windows 8.1 to my ASUS computer, it works and I installed my drivers. But for some reason when I connect it to an external display and open windows store, the computer crashes. (`BSOD VIDEO_TDR_FALIURE`) can someone help me with this?

PC specs:

```
ASUS X101CH PC

Windows 8.1

Intel Atom CPU N2600 @ 1.60GHz

1GB RAM

32 Bit (x86 based processor)

External Monitor: 1920x600

PC screen: 1024x600
```

I tried the win10 dev preview with the same specs above and **all metro apps worked.**

Why is this the case? How can I resolve the windows 8.1 problem?

Comment: Your question is too vague. We can help here but you need to offer more information around you problem. what have you tried? have you ruled anything out?

Comment: I have tried resizing the screen resolution on the external display, I have looked up and researched and researched but there are no answers.

Comment: which driver version do you use?

Comment: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series driver version 8.14.8.1075

Comment: try driver 8.14.8.1096: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/23473/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-3600-Series-for-Windows-7-32-bit

Comment: Downloaded it, It still crashes. Its the latest. I found out when ASUS were fishing out outdated versions. They don't update it anymore. (Laptop is from 2012)

Comment: in this case you're SOL. Buy a new notebook/tablet which fully supports Windows 8.1.

Comment: What does SOL mean? I can live without metro apps

Comment: **S**hit **o**ut of **l**uck it is internet slang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TDR is the Timeout, Detection, and Recovery component in Windows. What
>   happens is the Graphics Display driver for the installed graphics card
>   stops responding.

The most common reason for this issue is that the graphics device is being overloaded or used beyond its capabilities.  This happens most often when running graphic intensive applications, but can happen with any process that uses a large amount of graphic resources, such as when editing or creating videos.

In this case the simple act of attempting to set the resolution to 1920x600 is likely the cause since your hardware isn't very good.  You can try setting the resolution, of the external monitor, to something other then 1920x600.  `Modern UI` applications require a certain resolution to even work so be sure the resolution you set is above the required resolution.

If you are going to use an external monitor with this device make sure the `Start Screen` only exists on the laptop's display not the external display.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your suggestions, changing external display to 1024x768 and making sure the start menu is only on the PC. But it still crashes when opening a metro app. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Mrfunny744 - Just to be clear.  The act of extending the desktop to this external monitor causes the computer to crash?

Comment: Yes. That is correct